# Implementing Map using Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I want to implement Map Data structure using Arrays.

I'm interested to create two methods. Below is my code structure:

```
public class ImplementMap<K,V> {

    public void insert(K key, V value) { //to insert string

    }

    public V retrieve(K key) {//to retrieve value if key is given

    }

}
```

For example :

```
ImplementMap<String, String> newMap = new ImplementMap<>();

newMap.insert("IN", "India");

newMap.retrieve("IN");  India //Output should be India
```

I'm getting error as

> "Syntax error on token "." expected after this token" in line 37. I
>   have commented line 37 in code.

Please help me to get right output. This is my code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ImplementMap<K, V> {

    public void insert(K key[], V value[], int K, Object V) { //inserts 'IN' 'India'
        ArrayList<Object> newInsertion = new ArrayList<>();
        newInsertion.add(K, V); 
        System.out.println(newInsertion);


    }

   public void retrieve(K key[], int K){//has to retrieve 'India' 
     int[] index = null;
     int retrievevalue;
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    int findindex = index[K];
      retrievevalue = findindex + 1;
    System.out.println(retrievevalue);



}


ImplementMap<String, String> newmap = new ImplementMap<>();

newmap.insert("IN", "India"); // this is line 37 
newmap.retrieve("IN";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap that code in a method. For testing the easiest thing to do is add a "main" method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImplementMap<String, String> newmap = new ImplementMap<>();

    newmap.insert("IN", "India"); // this is line 37 
    newmap.retrieve("IN");
}
```

Comment: The method insert(String[], String[], int, Object) in the type ImplementMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
 The method retrieve(String[], int) in the type ImplementMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: You need to call your methods with the same arguments that they require. You've written your "insert" method so that it requires and array of K elements, an array of V elements, an integer and an object, but you're only handing it two parameters in the call, a string and a string

Comment: in fact, it looks like you've changed your method signatures from what the initial design was. Without knowing the lesson, I think you need to change them back to what you had initially

Comment: Hi mike, I can insert the data, but I am still trying to retrieving the data.

Comment: public void insert(String K, String V) { //inserts 'IN' 'India'
  ArrayList<Object> newInsertion = new ArrayList<>();
  newInsertion.add(K);
  newInsertion.add(V); 

    System.out.println(newInsertion);

  
 }

Comment: public class ImplementMap<K, V> {
 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     ImplementMap<String, String> newmap = new ImplementMap<>();

     newmap.insert("IN", "India"); // this is line 37 
    
 }

Comment: okay Sourabh, you've got so many other things that need to be fixed. I would suggest trying to find a computer lab at your school and see if someone there can help you out in the flesh.

Comment: first off, in the insert method... you've got your variable names confused with the types. "K" and "V" are the types of objects you're supposed to use. Not Strings. this allows you to use your map with other types of objects too

Comment: next, your insertion method is creating a new object (called "newInsertion") and adding some things to it, but not really doing anything with it. You need to save this object to the class itself, so that your retrieve method has access to the new object

Comment: next (and kind of part of the last one) your retrieve method is creating a new empty array and just retrieving empty objects from that array. It's not accessing any sort of memory from your map class itself

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I have made the code succesfully.